# How to update the list item from grid(custom web part)

Tags: c#, list, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, on-premises-instances

I have one list.in that list title column,Start date ,Due DAte ,Assigned To,Status column is there.And some entries also there.All the list items i am displaying in one grid.After that in that grid Status column i need to change as editable.Aftet that one button is there named as save.On click of save that particular row should change in list also.For example in Particular row status column i am changing as completed then in list also it should update as completed.Just imagine i have 3 rows.3 rows i edited the status as completed.After click save button in list also 3 rows should change as completed.

if login name =assigned to person then that particular row i am displaying in grid through c#.After that i tried to edit in the grid the from dropdown status column as completed.I have save button also.but i don't know how to update that in list.Is it possible? Because as far as i know in event receiver only i can update the list item.But i am trying in Custom web part.If it is possible Can u give c# code?